# Finding the MLE of parameter $\mu$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are a random sample of a continuous and strictly increasing distribution $F(x)$ with mean $\mu$. If

$$
Y_i = \begin {cases} 2 & \text{if}\ X_i>\mu \\
1 & \text{if} \ X_i\leq\mu  \end {cases}
$$

Determine the MLE of parameter $\mu$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would take a bet this is homework.  Should give it the homework tag.  As a hint, note that 
$$Pr(Y_i=1|\mu)=Pr(X_i\leq\mu|\mu)=F(\mu)=1-Pr(Y_i=2|\mu)$$

So the likelihood for the data is:

$$Pr(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)=\left[F(\mu)\right]^{n_1}\left[1-F(\mu)\right]^{n_2}$$

Where $n_1$ is the number of observed $Y_i$ which are equal to $1$ and $n_2$ is the number of observed $Y_i$ which are equal to $2$.  Obviously $n_1+n_2=n$

Comment: Would there be a combinatorial factor out the front of this?

Comment: @Glen_b - there would be, if I was calculating the sampling distribution of the sufficient statistic (either $ n_1 $ or $ n_2 $).  However, this is for a particular sequence of $ Y_i , X_i $ - the sequence that was observed.  Note that whether the combinatorical factor is there or not makes no difference to what the mle is though.

Comment: Ah, of course, it's for the n term(s). Yes, it makes no difference. Indeed being likelihood for $n_1$, this is fine. Thanks.